Getting SSL Browser Warning When Accessing Server On LAN
I purchased a public ssl certificate for my domain e.g simplycute.com that came with the public key and ca-bundle files.
I did cat <public cert> <ca-bundle> > fullcert.crt and saved it.
On my nginx server I configured nginx to use the certificates using
ssl_certificate \etc\ssl\certs\fullcert.crt
ssl_certificate_key \etc\ssl\private\myprivatekey.key 

Files have 644 permission and owned by root.
I tested nginx using nginx -t, results came back OK.
I restarted nginx and opened firefox and entered my domain name https://simplycute.com and all worked fine. When I went to another machine on my LAN and typed the same url I get certificate warning error on firefox.
What could cause this problem? My DNS can resolve all hostnames
I was thinking of using Apache in case it has something to do with nginx.

" I get certificate warning error on firefox" - on what does the error exactly say? There is usually an "Advanced" button or similar for more details.

Issue was resolved. The ssl certificate need intermediate certs from sectigo which was provided to get a resolution.
